# Несколько покупок в приложении

Tags: android, in-app-purchases

Есть приложение, в котором есть возможность платного отключения рекламы. Реализацию этого функционала использовалась данная статья http://suvitruf.ru/2013/11/15/3362/ , на основе In-app purchase v3. Отключение рекламы происходит как нужно, но вот теперь появилась необходимость реализации еще одной покупки. Насколько я понял, то всю проверку на наличие купленной, а именно восстановление информации о покупке происходит в:

```
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    private static final String TAG = "QueryInventoryFinishedListener";

    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                         Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

        /*
         * Проверяются покупки. Обратите внимание, что надо проверить каждую
         * покупку, чтобы убедиться, что всё норм! см.
         * verifyDeveloperPayload().
         */

        Purchase purchase = inventory.getPurchase(Constants.SKU_ADS_DISABLE);
        PreferencesHelper.savePurchase(getApplicationContext(),
                PreferencesHelper.Purchase.DISABLE_ADS, purchase != null
                        && verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase));
        showAds(!PreferencesHelper.isAdsDisabled());
    }
};
```

по каким критериям проверять покупку, точнее в цикле по каким полям в объекте SkuDetails делать проверку? И насколько плохой вариант сохранять результат, типа флаг о наличии покупки, в SharedPreferances?

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я знаю, информация о купленных товарах хранится в Google Play. Так что хранить информацию о покупке в SharedPreferances не имеет смысла, так как после удаления приложения эта информация все равно исчезнет. К тому же информация о покупке уже хранится локально и не привязана к текущей установке приложения.

Узнать о том, куплен товар или нет, можно через метод inventory.hasPurchase(Constants.SKU_ADS_DISABLE). Также если товар уже был куплен, Google Play не позволит его купить повторно.

Думаю, что бы проверить покупку, необходимо знать её SKU. Так что врядли можно получить список доступных покупок без идентификаторов.